# Loop trought file and count selected instances

Tags: php

I have this file and i want to count the number of instances for each "ROBxx". The file can contain thousands of lines. What is the easiest way to loop trough and count?

2012.05.08 11:15:49 ROB52   4mm

2012.05.08 11:15:56 ROB42   5mm

2012.05.08 11:15:59 ROB30   4mm

2012.05.08 11:16:01 ROB52   4mm

2012.05.08 11:16:04 ROB42   2mm

2012.05.08 11:16:05 ROB06   4mm

2012.05.08 11:16:06 ROB52   4mm

2012.05.08 11:16:10 ROB52   4mm

2012.05.08 11:16:11 ROB30   3mm

The result of this file after count should be:

ROB52: 4

ROB42: 2

ROB30: 2

ROB06: 1

Thanks!

Comment: Google the preg_match() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$handle = fopen("input.txt", "r");
$hash = array();
if ($handle) {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                if(preg_match('/\b(ROB\d+)\b/',$buffer,$m)) {
                        $hash[$m[1]] = (isset($hash[$m[1]])?($hash[$m[1]]+1):1);
                }
        }
        foreach($hash as $k=>$v) {
                print "$k : $v\n";
        }
} else {
        // error openeing file.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i also have a secound criteria to handle. The ones in [], how can i first count for each uniqueue [] and then the Xmm?
2012.04.27 09:40:12 ROB43 [3] 3mm
2012.04.27 09:40:13 ROB52 [3] 3mm
2012.04.27 09:40:14 ROB10 [3] 3mm
2012.04.27 09:40:18 ROB06 [15]
2012.04.27 09:40:21 ROB42 [15]
2012.04.27 09:40:24 ROB43 [3] 3mm
2012.04.27 09:40:26 ROB42 [15]
2012.04.27 09:40:28 ROB43 [3] 3mm
2012.04.27 09:40:31 ROB10 [3] 3mm
2012.04.27 09:40:37 ROB43 [3] 3mm
2012.04.27 09:40:41 ROB42 [15]
2012.04.27 09:40:42 ROB10 [3] 3mm
2012.04.27 09:40:44 ROB52 [4] 4mm

Answer (score 0):

First, create a 2-Dimensional Array (or list or whatever) with a String and a integer. Now you can loop through each line and do following:

Cut out the "ROBxx" String and save it as String.

Check the 2-Dimensional Array for the String. if you found it, increase the count. If not already in the Array, add it and set the count to 1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = file_get_contents(filename)
$count = preg_match_all('/ROB[0-9]{2}/', $string, $aMatches);
```

Comment: Oh - "unset($aMatches)" if you don't want it - to free memory. Also "unset($string)" for that matter, if it's too large.